# convert string to double decimal point needs to be a point

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, double, viewbag

I have been looking around here and I have found this solution:

```
ViewBag.lon = double.Parse(parts[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

this is doing the trick... partially... When I put this value in my ViewBag and write it out, the '.' becomes a ',' suddenly... who can I fix this?

Seems like everything is going fine untill getting it out of the ViewBag... in the ViewBag they're all ok..

any solutions?

Comment: Could you show how are you using this `ViewBag.lon` value on the view?

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that your default culture uses a comma as decimal point (e.g. Spain). One way to force it, is to write it out providing a format string:

```
@(ViewBag.lon.ToString("#,##0.00"))
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: but it may not be a string... it needs to remain a '.' when I get the value from my viewbag and of type double..

Comment: it seems to me a problem in your UI culture try to set the proper culture in your config file